# mysql for each value in table 1 get all values from table 2

Tags: mysql

This problem is eating up my brain for the past few hours.

I have 2 tables:

```
**domain_pricing**
action  enum()
map varchar(10)
cost_price  varchar(10)
sale_price  varchar(10) 

**domain_mapping**
map varchar(10)
tld varchar(10)
```

map is common for both tables.
sample data:

```
**domain_pricing**
addnewdomain,dotbiz,12,13
renewdomain,dotbiz,12,13
transferdomain,dotbiz,12,13

**domain_mapping**
dotbiz,biz
dotbiz,fizz
dotbiz,jizz
```

what i need after join:

```
biz,addnewdomain,12,13
biz,renewdomain,12,13
biz,transferdomain,12,13
fizz,addnewdomain,12,13
fizz,renewdomain,12,13
fizz,transferdomain,12,13
jizz,addnewdomain,12,13
jizz,renewdomain,12,13
jizz,transferdomain,12,13
```

my query:

```
select m.tld,p.action,p.sales_price,p.cost_price from domain_pricing as p, domain_mapping as m where p.map=m.map
```

result:
    biz,addnewdomain,12,13
    biz,renewdomain,12,13
    biz,transferdomain,12,13
dats all, tried doing left join but that gave all values for biz then fizz,null,null and finally jizz,null,null

Can't figure out where i'm going wrong

Comment: Eh?  Your query [works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0689/1/0) for me.

Comment: you are right, my varchar limit trimmed off the big map values in the  which i overlooked which caused improper mapping. Marked this question to the mods for deletion.

Comment: Alternatively, post that as an answer to your own question in case other people run into a similar problem in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think solved your problem. And the best part is that there is nothing wrong with your query. ;-) You only made a typo in you query. That happens to everybody.

select m.tld,p.action,p.sale**s**_price,p.cost_price from domain_pricing as p, domain_mapping as m where p.map=m.map

It should be:

```
select m.tld,p.action,p.sale_price,p.cost_price from domain_pricing as p, domain_mapping as m where p.map=m.map
```

The difference is that you query looks for the non existing column sale**s**. The column you want is sale.

```
    CREATE TABLE domain_pricing (
  action enum('addnewdomain','renewdomain','transferdomain')  primary key,
  map varchar(10),
  cost_price  varchar(10),
  sale_price  varchar(10)
  );

CREATE TABLE domain_mapping(
  map varchar(10),
  tld varchar(10)
  );

INSERT INTO domain_pricing (action, map, cost_price, sale_price)
VALUES 
('addnewdomain','dotbiz',12,13),
('renewdomain','dotbiz',12,13),
('transferdomain','dotbiz',12,13);

INSERT INTO domain_mapping (map,tld)
VALUES 
('dotbiz','biz'),
('dotbiz','fizz'),
('dotbiz','jizz');

SELECT * FROM domain_pricing;

SELECT * FROM domain_mapping;

select m.tld,p.action,p.sale_price,p.cost_price from domain_pricing as p, domain_mapping as m where p.map=m.map;


select m.tld,p.action,p.cost_price, p.sale_price, from domain_pricing as p, domain_mapping as m where p.map=m.map;
```

See it in action: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6b83/7

B.T.W. I'm not sure why you would need enum for action? I would suggest to use an integer column for the primary key instead.

Comment: thanks for the effort, i really appreciate it and i need enum as there are only 3 values there. And my query was fine its just that i was silly and kept varchar length 10 and it did not accept the bigger values, making my fetched results incomplete leading me to think the fetched results were incomplete.

Comment: @Suyash great the hear that you were able to solve on you own and thanks for accepting my answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I always cringe when I see newer users or tutorials for newer users use the `,` for joins as oftentimes it produces results they don't expect.  I am a big believer in explicitly stating that type of join you are looking for such that other clearly understand your intent.  Try this:

```
SELECT m.tld,p.action,p.sales_price,p.cost_price
FROM domain_pricing AS p
INNER JOIN domain_mapping AS m WHERE p.map=m.map
```

Comment: Why should one expect different results with this query versus the OP's original one?

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you describe you need a CROSS JOIN.

```
SELECT m.tld, p.action, p.cost_price, p.sale_price
FROM domain_mapping m
CROSS JOIN domain_pricing p
```

This is called a *Cartesian product*, where you deliberately leave out the join condition, so that all rows from one table are mapped to all rows of the other table.  MySQL also calls this a *full join*.

Comment: Doesn't "*map is common for both tables*", together with the filter in the OP's query `p.map=m.map`, suggest the OP is *not* after a `CROSS JOIN` (even if though, in the example above, they produce identical results since all values of `map` are the same)?

Comment: cross join gives a cross of all values, i just want cross of tld and action where map is common